# Comparison of Python and R vocabularies

Tags: python, r, syntax, programming-languages

I was searching for language comparisons of R and Python and come across a comparison of vocabularies for R and JuliaLang. This is similar to what I was looking except for a different language.

[Comparing R and JuliaLang vocabularies](http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2012/04/09/comparing-julia-and-rs-vocabularies/)

Does anyone know if there is a similar comparison for R and Python? In this cheat-sheat like format.

Thanks.

**Update 24 July**

I found [this](http://hyperpolyglot.org/numerical-analysis) resource. There are a lot of gaps in it though.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check this sheet comparing Python, R and Matlab for numeric tools:

http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/matlab-python-xref.pdf

it assumes you have installed numpy, scipy and matplotlib and imported then with

```
from pylab import *
```

Comment: outstanding! Exactly what I wanted.